# Dashed underline in caption using ulem

Tags: captions, ulem

I'm trying to dashed underline a word in a caption using the `ulem` package. While the `\dashuline{}` command works fine everywhere else, I get "Undefined control sequence" as error message in caption.

```
\begin{figure}
    While it does work \dashuline{here}
    \caption{It does not work \dashuline{here}}
\end{figure}
```

Has anyone an idea why it doesn't work and how to get it working?

Comment: This does work correctly with ulem (and it should have been the case already back then given the last update of the package), ie \dashuline is already robust!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protecting the command should solve the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    While it does work \dashuline{here}
    \caption{It does not work \protect\dashuline{here}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]